# AWS Step Function to be an AWS Kinesis Data Stream Consumer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, aws-step-functions

I am new to the AWS ecosystem and I am trying to design a POT that involves sending data from an AWS Kinesis Data Stream to an AWS Step Function. I know I can make a Lambda function to consume the Kinesis Data Stream and invoke the Step Function from that Lambda, but I'm curious if I can bypass the Lambda and have the Step Function consume the Kinesis Data Stream directly. Within the Step Function designer you can make the Kinsis Data Stream's GetRecords API a state.

[image]

But once added, there is no way to point that state to my specific stream that I can see within the configuration. I can't find any documentation or examples on how to make an AWS Step Function a consumer of a Kinesis Data Stream. Being new to AWS I'm curious about two things:

- Is this possible to do
- If it is possible is this a good idea from an architecture standpoint.

Comment: Please note with Step Functions you pay for transitions, so if you have a big flow in Kinesis you'll pay a fortune for SF. In this case better to use something different than SF.

Comment: @Putnik I know this question could be seen as ambiguous, but for a big data flow what would you recommend as an alternative? IE, what would the best thing to hook Kinesis up to?

Comment: strongly depends on what you're going to do with the data. If you need to put it e.g. to S3 for future processing then I'd switch to Firehose because it can write to S3 directly. If you need to process on the fly then maybe EC2/containers. If you need image recognition - there are other tools. Just look over all possible consumers and besides everything else think how much they're good for big flow. E.g. be careful with big flows on lambda: sometimes it'll cost you a fortune but sometimes it's the only tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now do this using [EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/) Pipes, launched at re:Invent 2022.

Pipes allows you to configure a source, including [Kinesis Data Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/), and a target, including [Step Functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/), then it will take care of polling from your stream and reliably delivering events to the targets. You can optionally filter and enrich the data on the way through the pipe.

For more information on configuring Pipes with Kinesis Data Streams, check out this [documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-pipes-kinesis.html).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No.  Step Functions cannot be invoked directly as a Kinesis Data Streams consumer.

References:

- [Step Functions docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-invoke-sfn.html):  Invoke AWS Step Functions from other services
- [Kinesis docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/building-consumers.html): Reading Data from Amazon Kinesis Data Streams